# decodify � php characters

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, html-entities

I have a DB on utf8-bin Collation.
When I use this values I have a problem because the letter ò is display like �
I try with utf_encode()  htmlentities() base_64 ma nothing. 
There is a method for the problem inseta do replace of all this characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the utf8-unicode-ci ? Does the � appear when trying to display data in a web page ?

P.S. : Sorry for posting this here, I couldn't comment the OP's question.